# Python Registry Persistence

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, registry

I’m trying to make a python script that is persistent within the windows environment. I am using PyInstaller to create an exe. I have managed to get this script only to function on the Windows XP environment and not on any other versions of windows. I can move the exe to the %temp% folder, however It will not write to "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" within the registry. I’d love to have you guys give me your opinions on the code. Is there a more efficient way to write to the registry?

```
import sys, base64, os, socket, subprocess
from _winreg import *

def autorun(tempdir, fileName, run):
# Copy executable to %TEMP%:
    os.system('copy %s %s'%(fileName, tempdir))

# Queries Windows registry for the autorun key value
# Stores the key values in runkey array
    key = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, run)
    runkey =[]
    try:
        i = 0
        while True:
            subkey = EnumValue(key, i)
            runkey.append(subkey[0])
            i += 1
    except WindowsError:
        pass

# If the autorun key "helloworld" isn't set this will set the key:
    if 'helloworld' not in runkey:
        try:
            key= OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, run,0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
            SetValueEx(key ,'helloworld',0,REG_SZ,r"%TEMP%\hello.exe")
            key.Close()
        except WindowsError:
            pass

def hello():
    print "hello world"

def main():
    tempdir = '%TEMP%'
    fileName = sys.argv[0]
    run = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
    autorun(tempdir, fileName, run)
    hello()

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing with writing to registry is that you may find you need to be running the application as Administrator. This could be why you have different performances in different environments.

If you are not strictly bound to the registry, you could try using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to save information between sessions. This has the benefit of being cross platform.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I actually solved the issue, simply by changing HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE to HKEY_CURRENT_USER. I have a new issue though. For some reason its not automatically starting.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by replacing the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE value with HKEY_CURRENT_USER. I am still having an issue with the .exe file not running after restarting.

Comment: Use `REG_EXPAND_SZ` as the data type to make the Window shell expand the `%TEMP%` environment variable. However, I recommend expanding the path before writing it to the registry, e.g. `os.path.join(os.environ["TEMP"], "hello.exe")`. Definitely stick with `HKCU` instead of `HKLM`, since other users won't have access to the current user's temp directory.

Comment: This definitely makes it looks better with the full path, but it still wouldn't auto run. I don't know why =(

Comment: Are you using `HKCU` in both calls? Are you storing the value of `fileName` or hard coding 'hello.exe'? Are you sure the copy succeeded? I'd use [`shutil.copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) instead of the cmd shell, but if I did use cmd, I'd use quotes in case of spaces and check the call: `subprocess.check_call('copy "%s" "%s"' % (fileName, tempdir), shell=True)`.

Comment: Also watch out when using backslash in string literals. In this case the following isn't a problem: `"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"`, but you'll get burned by this eventually. Get in the habit of using raw strings for Windows paths.